# Trying to get property 'password' of non-object

Tags: php

I have a problem with this error code, when i intentionally failed to log in, it will pop out the error in the title above.

```
    if ($password == $user->password ) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user->u_id;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $user->u_name;

        header("Location: http://website/index/main.php");
    } else{
        echo"fail";
    }
```

So what should i do? well i thought of changing `echo "fail";` to `header("Location: http://website/index/login.php")` but that just seem plain wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: your code is truncated for us to determine the rest but if i had to guess `$user` won't be set if the username/email doesn't exist. but yeah if there's no username/email in your system don't let them in :D return them to the login screen, if the password is wrong don't hint them that too, just redirect them again back and username/password is doesn't exist

Comment: yah, from some other solution i found , it says it does not contain the following data in the database so it show up the error, what i wanted to know is there like any rejection code instead direct them back to login page

Comment: Before you get the password of $user object, check it for null by using isset, if(isset($user)) { //get the password and check it for equality } else //go to back to login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you get the password from the $user object check if it is NULL or not  by using isset method

```
 if(isset($user)){
 if ($password == $user->password ) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $user->u_id;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $user->u_name;

    header("Location: http://website/index/main.php");
  } else{
    //back to login page using header
 }
 }
else
{
//back to login page using header
}
```

Comment: I am glad to help :-)